# Is it required to enable FULL recovery mode of mssql database if CDC enable in the table level for AWS DMS on going repliation

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, cdc, aws-dms

AWS DMS recommends enabling FULL, Bulk logged recovery mode for ongoing replication tasks( [prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html#CHAP_Source.SQLServer.Prerequisites)) But is it required if the table is CDC enabled?

The current recovery mode of my database is Simple and I can't change it for multiple reasons. So I am curious if CDC is enabled for the table, is it required to enable the Full recovery?

Answer (score 0):

From the link:

> During CDC, AWS DMS needs to look up SQL Server transaction log backups to read changes.

If they read changes from the log backups, then Simple recovery won't work as there are no log backups.

And I would be dubious about Bulk Logged actually working.

Comment: AWS DMS will read log backups if the MS-CDC is not enabled right? I am asking about the scenario when database-level MS-CDC is enabled. Does it still need to read logs? Since MS-CDC creates a table and tracks the changes, I don't think so.

Comment: I have no idea.